Top Five As Flags
Which flag should be placed in the rectangle below?



It should be

 the flag of Malaysia:



That's because

 if we index into each of the countries provided by the three numbers within their flags, we get abbreviations of the top sports leagues in the United States. For example, we have Finland and 314, so we take the 3rd, 1st, and 4th letters of FINLAND, which are NFL, aka the National Football League. Doing the same with NETHERLANDS, NAMIBIA, and BELGIUM give us the NHL (National Hockey League), NBA (National Basketball Association), and MLB (Major League Baseball), respectively. The NFL, NHL, NBA, and MLB are collectively referred to as the Big Four, but sometimes, they're grouped in with a fifth league. That league is Major League Soccer, also known as MLS. If that's what's missing, we need a nation whose first letter is M, third letter is L, and sixth letter is S - and that's MALAYSIA!

We can also note that

 the small numbers in parentheses at the top of each flag are enumerations of the sports themselves - namely American (or gridiron) football, ice hockey, basketball, baseball, and soccer.

